# Switch to a camera once it's loaded three js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, three.js

I would like to know if there is à way to switch to a camera once an object containing a perspective camera is loaded. In my case i have an object avatar containing à perspective camera and i would like to use it either directly when it's loaded or switch to it once it's loaded.
i read about orbit conrols but everything i tried with it did not succeed :

```
const fAddSc = function ( obj ) {
      // Add the loaded object to the scene
      let cam = obj.getObjectByName("PerspectiveCamera 1");


      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(cam.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, cam.near, cam.far);
      camera.position.copy(cam.position);
      camera.rotation.copy(cam.rotation);


      obj.position.x=0;
      obj.position.z=-4;
      obj.position.y=0.5;
      scene.add(obj);

      const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
      controls.enabled = true;

      console.log(controls);
      console.log(scene.activeCamera);
    };
```

i use

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import OrbitControls from 'orbit-controls-es6';
```

Every help is welcome, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think i just found the answer to my question only problem it's not clean.

```
const fAddSc = function ( obj ) {
        let grChar= new THREE.Group();
        camera.position.set(0,1,-4);
        camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
        obj.position.x=0;
        obj.position.z=-4;
        obj.position.y=0.5;
        grChar.add(obj,camera);
        scene.add(grChar);
    };
```